# Sly Deal - Stealing a Wild Card

Tags: monopoly-deal

The below is from the help section of the [Monopoly Deal](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Monopoly_Deal)

> **Sly Deal**
>
> Steal a property card or a **property wild card** from any other player and **add it to your property collection**. You cannot steal a card from a full set of properties. Can also be banked as money. Bank value: 3M.

**Question**: Can I still take the property wild card using **Sly Deal** if ***none*** of my property cards are displayed on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Sly Deal to steal the wildcard.

Card text:

> Steal a property card or a property wild card from any other player.

You then add it to your property collection (as the only card in your property collection).

The only issues that might lead to a negative answer are:

1. can a wildcard be played alone?
2. what is your "property collection"? Do you start with a collection of zero, or does the collection not exist when you have no cards?

If either of these are answered in the negative ("no collection" being the negative in the second case), then these might be obstacles to stealing a wildcard with Sly Deal if you have no other cards in your collection.

Hasbro has answered that first one in the affirmative (despite the language in the rulebook that can easily be read to the contrary). See below for that.

As for the second, well, since the regular play of cards is to your property collection, if the answer here were negative, you could never play any cards. So clearly the collection is all the cards (zero or more) that you have collected.

Back to the first point, see answers as quoted [on this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/375594/article/3216057#3216057):

> The "Property Wild Card" (the ones that count as any color property):
> Can this card be played alone (i.e.: as a property in a color group the player doesn't already have one of)?
>
> Hasbro Games: Yes.

As the only card in the collection, it wouldn't collect rent (having no text of its own to declare the rent to be charged).

That's on the FAQ, as quoted in [this thread on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/419381/playing-wild-card-begin-new-property-set):

> Q: Can I put a multicoloured (10-colour) property wildcard down on its own to start creating a set?
>
> A: Yes, you can. But you can’t charge rent on it until you’ve added another card to it, because it has no value on its own. It would make more sense to add it on to an existing Property card or set of cards.

So, with nothing preventing you from following the instructions on Sly Deal, you can steal the wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only part in your answer which I am looking for is `Yes, you can steal it and add it as the only card in your property collection.` The two questions that follows is not what I am looking for :) My question is very simple.. **Can I steal the wild card or not using Sly deal?** Whatever the answer is (yes/No), I need a Hasbo backed documentation which unfortunately none of the answers (incl yours) have given me....

Comment: The first sentence is the answer: Yes, you can steal it (using Sly Deal).  The remainder of he text is the documentation that supports that answer. Which part of the documentation is unclear?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I've clarified the chain of reasoning here.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. This ceratingly clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can take. In fact, you can rotate the Wild Card before placing a new card on the table to change its color and add your new property. ;)

Comment: Joker? There is no joker in monopoly deal

Comment: Hahahaha... This was a translation error. In Brazil we call Wild Card from Joker. I will edit my answer!
Thank's!

Comment: Thank you. Can you support this statement with some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can still steal someone's property (wild or otherwise) using Sly Deal, even if you have not yet played any of your own property cards.

In that case, your existing "property collection" starts with zero properties, then once you "**add (the stolen card) to your property collection**", it has a size of one.

Comment: Thank you. Can you support this statement with some documentation.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Dunno, seems like more of a philosophical question than a rules one. You can "add a card to the discard pile" even if you're the first player and the discard is currently empty. You can "add a card to your bank" even if you don't have any cards there yet. Similarly, your "property collection" is the set of property cards in front of you; at the beginning of the game it has zero items, but is still a designated region of the table. You can "add" cards to this set by playing them from your hand, by stealing them, or by collecting them from other players via payment cards.

Comment: Perhaps the most applicable part of the rules is the portion that describes the 3 different places you can play cards: http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=play#top

Answer (score 0):

Excerpts from the rules for Monopoly Deal by Hasbro

**THE CARDS IN MORE DETAIL**

*Sly Deal*

Steal a property from any other player and add it to your collection. You cannot steal a card from a full set of properties.
Can also be banked as money.

**ON YOUR TURN**

PLAY UP TO 3 CARDS from your hand, onto the table in front of you.

A. PUT MONEY/ACTION CARDS INTO YOUR OWN BANK

B. PUT DOWN PROPERTIES INTO YOUR OWN COLLECTION

Lay property cards down in front of you to build up your property sets.

(End of excerpts)

The rules clearly state that either of these actions mean that the cards must be played from from your hand onto the table in front of you.

So, either way, you must be able to place the stolen card in front of you, and not keep it in your hand. As long as the card ends up in your collection by the end of your turn, you can steal it.

Comment: Sorry, it's confusing what you are trying to say.. So let me rephrase it.. I can steal a property wild card and place it on the table using Sly Deal even if none of my property cards are displayed on the table?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Exactly...

Comment: Ok I re-read your answer again and I am not sure which part says that "clearly"

Comment: @SiddharthRout : The rule «Lay property cards down in front of you to build up your property sets.» means that you take cards from your hand and lay them on the table, thereby building your property set. The «Sly Deal» states that you can include the stolen card in your property set. You cannot place the stolen card down alone.

Comment: `You cannot place the stolen card down alone.` Exactly. And that is where the confusion is. The Wild Card is supposd to be put on top of another property card. But like I mentioned there is no card on my table.

Answer (score 0):

No how can you add it to a property collection if you don’t have any down? If you have no properties on the board you **cannot** take a property-wild card.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My dilemma is whether I CAN or CANNOT has to be supported with valid supporting document from Hasbro. Unfortunately, I have not found any such document without which, it becomes subjective to one's personal understanding :)